# Getting Accelerometer data on windows Surface pro using Qt c++?

Tags: c++, windows, sensors, qt5.5

How can I get Accelerometer data on windows Surface pro using Qt c++? I tried the below code but it gives only 0,0,0 values in all scenarios. Please help me!

```
   QAccelerometer *accmeter = new QAccelerometer();

    accmeter->start();
    QAccelerometerReading *reading = new QAccelerometerReading();

    qreal x = reading->x();
    qreal y = reading->y();
    qreal z = reading->z();

    QMessageBox *box = new QMessageBox();
    box->setText("x="+ QString::number(x)+ "\n" "y="+ QString::number(y)+ "\n" "z="+ QString::number(z)+ "\n");
    box->exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the accelerometer data, it is recommended by the Qt company to listen to the signal `readingChanged`, as no data is immediately available after starting the sensor. You code would be shortened to something like this, with `accMeter` being changed to be a member of the class:

```
    accmeter = new QAccelerometer();
    connect(accmeter, SIGNAL(readingChanged()), this, SLOT(checkReading()));
    accmeter->start();
```

and then add a member function to your class called `checkReading`:

```
MyClass::checkReading() {
    qreal x = accmeter->reading()->x();
    qreal y = accmeter->reading()->y();
    qreal z = accmeter->reading()->z();
    QMessageBox *box = new QMessageBox();
    box->setText("x="+ QString::number(x)+ "\n" "y="+ QString::number(y)+ "\n" "z="+ QString::number(z)+ "\n");
    box->exec();
}
```

Note that in order to perfectly replicate the  code you had above you should append `disconnect(accmeter, SIGNAL(readingChanged()), this, SLOT(checkReading()));` as the last line to the member function.

Comment: Thanks user3147395, for the suggestion but the signal _readingChanged()_ doesn't seem to fire anytime on windows surface pro tablet device, and thus the Qmessagebox also doen't execute. Am I doing anything wrong, Please suggest me any solution or is this is a bug in Qt5.5.?

Comment: The above is the way it was shown to be implemented in the Qt docs here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsensor.html#start. Make sure you've added the slot in your class header and there are no misspelling of the slot name, as  I don't believe that a misspelled slot name leads to a compiler error.